# MaterialTable: Display html tag on field property

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the MaterialTable library to render a table grid for my react application.

Source: [Material Table Github](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table)

After doing an API request, the server returns an object with
an HTML tag as this one:

```
  {
    "name": "Test",
    "link": "https://google.com",
    "httpLink": "<a href='https://google.com'>google</a>"
  }
```

On the client, I have the component rendering this data and I would like to display the rendered HTML tag or to wrap the link in an HTML tag and display only the word in between.

```
            columns={[
              { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
              { title: 'LinkString', field: 'link'},
              { title: 'Link', field: 'httpLink'},         
            ]}
```

I tried wrapping the link field on a tag, but that doesn't work and I can't display anything on the page.

The httpLink will display a string instead of rendering the tag and displaying the word google.

#### The desired output:

#### Name   | Link

Test   | google

#### The output:

#### Name   | Link

Test   | `<a href='https://google.com'>google</a>`

I had a look at the docs but could not find anything on the matter.

[Material Table Docs](https://mbrn.github.io/material-table/#/)

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom render feature

```
columns={[
              { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
              { title: 'LinkString', field: 'link'},
              { title: 'Link', field: 'httpLink', render: rowData => <a href={rowData.link}>{rowData.name}</a>},         
            ]}
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert String tag to Real DOM in React , try this

```
columns={[
          { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
          { title: 'LinkString', field: 'link'},
          { title: 'Link', field:  <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: 'httpLink'}} />},         
        ]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to do it this way:

```
columns={[
          { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
          { title: 'LinkString', field: 'link'},
          { title: 'Link', field: httpLink ,
            render: (row) => {
            return <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: row.httpLink}} />
            },
          },         
        ]}
```